# Quasi-coherent sheaves of algebras over affine scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-schemes

Hi there I am study algebraic geometry for the first time and I have a question. If we consider an affine scheme $\operatorname{Spec}(R)$, is the category of quasi-coherent sheaves of $\mathcal{O}_{R}$-algebras equivalent to the category of finitely generated $A$-algebras? Can you provide a reference?

Comment: **Note:** The construction in Hartshorne may be used as follows: View $A$ as a left $R$-module and construct the quasicoherent $\mathcal{O}_S$-module $\tilde{A}$ where $S:=Spec(R)$. From the definition in HH it follows $\tilde{A}(U)$ has canonically the structure of commutative $\mathcal{O}_S(U)$-algebra for any open set $U$ and the restriction maps are maps of rings. The definition in HH gives  for any open sets $V \subseteq U$ canonical restriction maps

$$\rho_{UV}: \tilde{A}(U) \rightarrow \tilde{A}(V)$$
that are maps of rings.

Comment: The question has been answered before: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3362192/noetherian-r-algebra-corresponds-to-a-coherent-sheaf-of-rings-on-operatornam/3940211#3940211

Comment: There are many details to be checked, but in the language of Hartshorne: Let $\tilde{R}(U)$ be the set of functions $s: U \rightarrow \prod_{\mathfrak{p}} R_{\mathfrak{p}}$ satisfying the criteria in $HH. Def.II.5.1$. Each module $R_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is canonically a ring, and this structure induce canonically a ring structure on $\tilde{R}(U)$. The canonical restriction map $\rho: \tilde{R}(U) \rightarrow \tilde{R}(V)$ is a map of rings, hence $\tilde{R}$ is a sheaf of commutative $\mathcal{O}_S$-algebras.

Comment: Conversely given a quasi coherent sheaf of commutative $\mathcal{O}_S$-algebras $\mathcal{R}$, it follows there is an isomorphism $\mathcal{R}≅\tilde{R}$ where $R:=H^0(S,\mathcal{R})$ as $\mathcal{O}_S$-modules. The $A$-module $R$ is a commutative $A$-algebra and you may prove that the isomorphism of $\mathcal{O}_S$-modules $R≅\tilde{R}$ is an isomorphism of $\mathcal{O}_S$-algebras. You do not need to "invoke category theory" to conclude - the result is an elementary result.

Comment: The sheaves of $\mathcal{O}_S$-modules  $\mathcal{R}$ and $\tilde{R}$ have by definition isomorphic stalks: For any prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}\subseteq A$ it follows $\tilde{R}_{\mathfrak{p}} \cong \mathcal{R}_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is an isomorphism of rings. This implies that the canonical isomorphism of $\mathcal{O}_S$-algebras $\phi:\mathcal{R} \cong \tilde{R}$ is in fact an isomorphism of quasi coherent $\mathcal{O}_S$-algebras.

Comment: There is another approach: Since tensor product commutes with limits it follows there is for any $A$-module $M$ and any open set $U \subseteq S:=Spec(A)$ an isomorphism of $\mathcal{O}_S(U)$-modules $\tilde{M}(U):= lim_{D(f) \subseteq U} M_f \cong lim_{D(f) \subseteq U}(A_f \otimes_A M) \cong M\otimes_A lim_{D(f) \subseteq U}A_f \cong M\otimes_A \mathcal{O}_S(U)$.

Comment: Hence in the case of a commutative $A$-algebra $R$ it follows $\tilde{R}(U) \cong R \otimes_A \mathcal{O}_S(U)$. Hence $\tilde{R}(U)$ is canonically a commutative $A$-algebra since it is the tensor product of two commutative $A$-algebras. The restriction maps are canonically maps of rings. Hence the sheaf $\tilde{R}$ is canonically a sheaf of commutative $\mathcal{O}_S$-algebras. This approach simplifies the construction and you do not need to "invoke monodial objects" in various "dubious categories".

Answer (score 4):

What you write is not quite correct - the category of quasi-coherent $\mathcal{O}_R$-algebras is equivalent to the category of *all* $R$-algebras (with no finite-generation hypothesis).

This can be broken down in to two parts: first, the fact that categories of $R$-modules and quasi-coherent $\mathcal{O}_R$-modules are equivalent; second, the fact that an algebra is characterized by being a monoid object in the module category, and this property is preserved under equivalence. A reference for the first part could be [Stacks 01IB](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01IB) or Hartshorne proposition II.5.5, and a reference for the second part could be [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monoid+in+a+monoidal+category) or any abstract algebra text that defines an algebra in terms of the multiplication map $m:A\otimes_R A\to A$, unit map $\eta:R\to A$, and various compatibilities between them. (You may also need something like [Stacks 0073](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0073) to convince yourself that a sheaf of algebras is a sheaf of modules with an algebra structure, or this may be obvious to you.)